# Java Applet with External Jar

Tags: java, jar, applet, compilation

Hi guys
I have an **Applet** in `MyApplet.java` file. It uses external .jar libraries and I have to get it work on a Web Browser.
1) I am a complete newbie in writing custom classpath, manifest ecc... which is the correct way to **compile** my .java file to get the .class?
2) Once i have the .class file, what i have to do in my **webspace**? where to put the jar files? what i have to write in my html page?

A step by step tutorial would be awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are nice resources out there, for example "The Java Tutorial", which has a section on [How to write Applets](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html).

But you seem to need even more basic advise on compiling - so take a look at [Getting Started](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html), and later at [Deployment](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/index.html). Then come back if you have more concrete problems.